# constexpr : literal class type copy behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, constexpr

let's take the following code:

```
class   const_int                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  constexpr const_int(int data) : data_(data) {}                                                                                                                                                                     
  constexpr const_int(const const_int &) = default;                                                                                                                                                                  
  constexpr const_int(const_int &&) = default;                                                                                                                                                                       

private:                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  int   data_;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
};

class   test                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                              

  constexpr static const const_int      USER = 42;                                                                                                                                                                

  constexpr static const double         NATIVE = 4.2;                                                                                                                                                                
};

// constexpr const const_int test::USER;

void    pass_by_copie(double)                                                                                                                                                                                        
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}

void    pass_by_copie(const_int)                                                                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}

void    pass_by_const_ref(const const_int&)                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}

void    pass_by_rvalue_ref(const_int&&)                                                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}

int     main(void)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

  pass_by_copie(test::NATIVE);                                                                                                                                                                                       

  pass_by_copie(test::USER);                                                                                                                                                                                         

  pass_by_const_ref(test::USER);                                                                                                                                                                                         

  pass_by_rvalue_ref(const_int(test::USER));                                                                                                                                                                         

  return (0);                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

Both of the following lines :

```
pass_by_copie(test::USER);
pass_by_const_ref(test::USER);
```

produce the following error under `g++ 4.7` :

> undefined reference to `test::USER'

I am aware of the fact that there is no instance of `test::USER`. (the line is commented on purpose)

---

I have two questions :

1. Why is an explicit instance of `test::USER` needed while no explicit instance of `test::NATIVE` is needed to call the function `pass_by_copie`?
2. Why can i call `pass_by_rvalue_ref` by explicity creating a temporary copie from `test::USER` while the compiler is unable (or doesn't want) to create the same copie implicitly himself when calling `pass_by_copie` with `test::USER` ?

Thank you

Comment: FYI: The singular of `copies` is spelled `copy`.

Comment: @Ben sorry, my current most used language is french where "copy" is spelled "copie", i'll try to avoid that mistake in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang 4.1 gives me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::USER", referenced from:
      _main in Untitled-gXrry2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm assuming what's going on here is `test::NATIVE` can be simply replaced with the value `4.2` where it's used, and doesn't actually require a symbol. But `test::USER`, being an instance of a class rather than a scalar, does require a symbol so that all references to `test::USER` refer to the same object. Given this, you actually do need the explicit instance.

Comment: Incidentally, even the `pass_by_rvalue_ref()` line produces the same error if I comment out the other two.

Comment: At least Clang seems more consistent in its behavior. And your answer to question 1 seems logical, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From section 3.2 of C++11:

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is *odr-used* unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied.

and

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program

So the definition is required because `test::USER` is odr-used, and apparently it is odr-used because it does not immediately undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  That surprises me, the call to `pass_by_copie` looks like it performs an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: Now I wonder when an expression with possibly cv-qualified class type ever would undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: First, thanks for the quotes from the standard.
Would it make sense to believe that the explicit call of the copy constructor makes it easier for the compiler to notice the constant expression since that constructor is declared as constexpr, while the implicit copy makes it more subtle for the compiler to deduce that the object can be copied at compile time ?